# select Nodes from an XML, that contains certain string in one of its attributes

Tags: xml, xpath

Im trying to select nodes that contain a given string in one of its attributes, but it seems that I can only do it on a certain attribute.

```
var tempUsers = xmlDocument.selectNodes("//Users/*[contains(@Id,'TEXT')]");
```

I guess that instead of @Id I can write something else to check all the attributes of a node and not only the Id.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@*` in xpath to select all attributes, but the naive

```
//Users/*[contains(@*,'TEXT')]
```

will *not* do what you expect. The `contains` function expects its arguments to be strings, so if you give it a node set instead it will first convert the node set to a string (by taking the string value of the *first* node in the set) and then use that value in the function. Instead you need to say

```
//Users/*[@*[contains(.,'TEXT')]]
```

which will find all `Users` elements in the document and then select all their child elements that have any attribute whose value contains the substring `TEXT`.

Comment: @yoni If the answer worked for you please consider _accepting_ it by clicking the green tick mark to the left. If you have a track record of accepting good answers people will be more willing to answer your future questions.

Comment: no problem @Ian. another thing, Im trying to make a "NOT contains" statment, but without any success. can you help me pls? xmlDocument.selectNodes("//Users/*[not[@*[contains(.,'TEXT')]]]"); what is wrong here?

Comment: You need round brackets `not(...)` instead of square ones `not[...]`. That expression is looking for elements called `not` that have an attribute containing TEXT.

Comment: I have another question @Ian. 
I want to do the same search (`contains`) but search only 2 out of 5 attributes. for example: if Im having attributes "ID" "name" "address" "phone" "gender", I want to check only if "ID" "name" and "phone" containing the given text.
`tempNodes = xmlDocument.selectNodes("//Users/*[not(@*contains(.,'searchText')])]");`
now Im searching all the attributes and I want it to search only the given attributes. 
thanks a lot,
Yoni.

Comment: You should really ask separate questions as, well, _separate questions_ (i.e. ask a new StackOverflow question rather than commenting on an existing one).  In this case the clearest would probably be just to say `//Users/*[not(contains(@ID, 'TEXT'))][not(contains(@name, 'TEXT'))]` etc. though if you have lots of attributes you could say `//Users/*[not((@ID|@name|@phone)[contains(., 'TEXT')])]`

Comment: OK, next time Ill separate them.
thanks for the answer, you really helped.